# Calculate daily sums in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sum

I am fairly new in postgres and what am trying to do is calculate sum values for each day for every month (i.e daily sum values). Based on scattering information I came up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumvalues() RETURNS double precision AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 0..31 LOOP
   SELECT SUM("Energy") 
   FROM "public"."EnergyWh" e
   WHERE  e."DateTime" = day('01-01-2005 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL 'i' DAY);
   END LOOP;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
ALTER FUNCTION public.sumvalues()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The query returned successfully, so I thought I had made it. However when am trying to insert the values of the function to a table (which maybe wrong):

```
INSERT INTO "SumValues"
("EnergyDC") 

    (
     SELECT sumvalues()
     );
```

I get this:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "01-01-2005 00:00:00"
LINE 3:    WHERE  e."DateTime" = day('01-01-2005 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL...

I tried to debug it myself but yet am not sure, which of the two I am doing wrong (or both) and why.

Here is an example of [EnergyWh](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a2487/1/0)

(am using systemid and datetime as composite PK, but that should not matter)

Comment: please put table schema and some sample data. or create SQL FIDDLE for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see GROUP BY clause http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-agg.html

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM e."DateTime"), EXTRACT(month FROM e."DateTime"), 
       EXTRACT(year FROM e."DateTime"), sum("Energy")
   FROM "public"."EnergyWh" e
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

but following query should to work too:

```
SELECT e."DateTime"::date, sum("Energy")
   FROM "public"."EnergyWh" e
  GROUP BY 1
```

I am using a short syntax for GROUP BY ~ GROUP BY 1 .. group by first column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it seemed to be quite easier this way :). The 1st piece of code actually worked (but not the 2nd one).

Comment: sure, it needs casting to date - fixed

Answer (score -2):

Here is simple Example that can help you:

**Table :**

```
create table demo (value double precision);
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sumvalues() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    inte text;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 0..31 LOOP
    inte := 'INSERT INTO demo SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM TIMESTAMP ''01-01-2005 00:00:00''+ INTERVAL '''||i||' Days'')';
    EXECUTE inte;
   END LOOP;

END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF;
ALTER FUNCTION public.sumvalues()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

**Function Call**

```
SELECT sumvalues();
```

**Output**

```
 SELECT * FROM demo;
```

Here if you want to use some variable value into SQL query than you must have to use some **DYNAMIC QUERY** for that.

Reference : [Dynamic query in pgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html)

Comment: please left reason -ve for what?

Comment: My *guess* would be someone down voted this because you have not really explained what you changed and why; simply dumped the changed code. But that's only a guess.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped on how to view the results of my function as well as how to use the intervals properly. It's what I initially tried to do, but since this result gives me the "day" and not the sum value of the "Energy", I'd rather go for the first solution from Pavel Stehule in this case ;).

Comment: I've downvoted because 1) the claim that _you must have to use DYNAMIC QUERY_ is just wrong: `i*interval '1 day'` is what should be used when `i` is a parameter, and 2) suggesting INSERTs that don't sum anything for a question about SELECTing a sum doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Dynamic SQL should by last way - mainly for beginners - there is more possibility to write code with performance or security issues.

Comment: @Pavel Stehule : In addition to the above, is there any way I could only choose to appear the results for just a specific year like for ex. 2006? I still want the daily sums but for only 2006. How is this going to go? Timestamp gives me a hard time...

Comment: @Elena_K sure, use WHERE clause - WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM e."DateTime") = 2006 like classic query